# Minimization of a function with iterative bounds in Python

Tags: python, scipy, numeric, numerical-methods, scipy-optimize-minimize

I'm trying to minimize a function of `N` parameters (e.g. `x[1],x[2],x[3]...,x[N]`) where the boundaries for the minimization depend on the minimized parameters themselves. For instance, assume that all values of `x` could vary between 0 and 1 in such a way that the summing then all I got 1, then I have the following inequalities for the boundaries:

```
0 <= x[1] <= 1
x[1] <= x[2] <= 1 - x[1]
x[2] <= x[3] <= 1-x[1]-x[2]
...
x[N-1] <= x[N] <= 1-x[1]-x[2]-x[3]-...-x[N]
```

Does anyone have an idea on how can I construct some algorithm like that on python? Or maybe if I can adopt an existent method from Scipy for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb: As soon as your boundaries depend on the optimization variables, they are inequality constraints instead of boundaries. Using 0-based indices, your inequalities can be written as

```
# left-hand sides
        -x[0] <= 0
x[i] - x[i+1] <= 0 for all i = 0, ..., n-1

# right-hand sides
sum(x[i], i = 0, .., j) - 1 <= 0 for all j = 0, .., n
```

Both can be expressed by a simple matrix-vector product:

```py
import numpy as np

D_lhs = np.diag(np.ones(N-1), k=-1) - np.diag(np.ones(N))
D_rhs = np.tril(np.ones(N))

def lhs(x):
    return D_lhs @ x

def rhs(x):
    return D_rhs @ x - np.ones(x.size)
```

As a result, you can use `scipy.optimize.minimize` to minimize your objective function subject to `lhs(x) <= 0` and `rhs(x) <= 0` like this:

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# minmize expects eqach inequality constraint in the form con(x) >= 0,
# so lhs(x) <= 0 is the same as -1.0*lhs(x) >= 0
con1 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: -1.0*lhs(x)}
con2 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: -1.0*rhs(x)}

result = minimize(your_obj_fun, x0=inital_guess, constraints=(con1, con2))
```

Comment: Thank you @joni. Reviewing the question I noticed that the second condition is wrong since summing all values I NEED to have 1, to do this I have to impose `sum(x[i], i=0,...,j) = 1 for all j = 0,..., n`. Which will actually reduce the number of minimization parameters since the last one can be found directly by this condition. Can you help on how can I overcome this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @MateusForcelini Then you only need to change con2 from 'ineq' to 'eq'. In case you only want to impose `x[0]+...+x[1]=1` you can define `def rhs(x): return np.sum(x)-1`

Comment: Thank you @joni, I'm still having some issues with the code since I have two more arrays of variables that I want to minimize together with their respective constraints. More specifically I don't know how can I specify them on the function and on the scipy.minimize. For instance, I have three N-dimension arrays, say `x`, `a` and `b` and each of them have 2 constraints like the one you showed how to address. How can I specify on the minimize function that I want two minimize the parameters in those 3 arrays? And on the function, should I specify them in some way?

Comment: I'd love to edit the question but I can't since there is an edit suggestion pending and I cannot review it;

Comment: @MateusForcelini You can set z = (x, a, b) such that z is an array with 3*N variables.  Then you only need to write your constraints as functions of z and use `x, a, b = np.split(z, N)` inside your constraints in order to express them only in terms of x, a or b. However, I think it would be better to ask a separate question instead of discussing it in the comments.

Comment: Thank you @joni, I just asked a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70848474/python-minimization-of-a-function-with-constraints